# ActiveXObject FileSystemObject not releasing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, activexobject, fso

I have a Javascript function that saves JSON data locally, using an ActiveXObject in IE9. It links into FileSystemObject or FSO scripting for file access.

If this Javascript function is run more than once, I get an error in IE debugger: "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" pointing to `ts = savefile.OpenAsTextStream(2);`

Why will it run just fine the first time, but not after that? My best guess is that something's not being released properly, although I can find no information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59(v=vs.84).aspx) (or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx)).

Here's the code:

```
function SaveMyJSON() {
    var ts; 
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var savefilepath = "C:\\MyFolder\\saveFile.json"
    var savefile = fso.GetFile(savefilepath);

    // open for writing only, value 2, overwriting the previous
    // contents of the file
    ts = savefile.OpenAsTextStream(2);

    var myTestJson = {"id1" : "one", "id2" : "two"};

    // copy to json
    ts.WriteLine(myTestJson);

    ts.Close;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This complies with SO's standards. Perhaps you couldn't help it because this is an ActiveX problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Close` method needs empty parenthesis after it, like so:

```
ts.Close();
```

Ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb3tbdkw(v=vs.84).aspx) for more info.